# How do I combine two Texture2Ds, in C# Xna?

Tags: c#, xna

What i'm trying to do is put one smaller texture2d into another bigger texture2d at a certain point in the bigger texture2d.
I have tried this method:

```
public void DrawBlock(Texture2D block, int xPos, int yPos)
    {
        Color[] blockData = new Color[block.Width * block.Height];
        Color[] mapData = new Color[map.Width * map.Height];
        block.GetData(blockData);
        map.GetData(mapData);
        for (int x = 0; x < block.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < block.Height; y++)
            {
                mapData[((y + yPos) * map.Width) + (x + xPos)] = blockData[(y * block.Width) + x];
            }
        }
        map.SetData(mapData);
    }
```

And then calling it:

```
DrawBlock(blockTexture, 10, 10);
```

But whenever I debug, I'm prompted with this error (pointed at map.SetData(Color[])):

```
"You may not call SetData on a resource while it is actively set on the GraphicsDevice. Unset it from the device before calling SetData."
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to manipulate the texture in the Draw loop. Why? I'm pretty sure that manipulating a texture is somewhat of a heavy operation, so I recommend rather doing it in Initialize or LoadContent.

Comment: or make sure that this is executed only once, and only when needed and in Update loop.